# How to group data from database and display in html

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a 3 different tables, table A, Table B and Table AB(associative table). I want to group the information from table A (based on a group name: same group name data group together). I have the following python code

```
class GroupView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "group.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(GroupView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['ngapp'] = "groups"
        c = AB.objects.values_list('AB_B_id', flat=True).order_by("orderg")
        cols = A.objects.get(id=1).num_cols
        context['assign_group'] = c
        context['colmd'] = 12/cols
        return context
```

and am passing it into my html as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="GroupCtrl">
        {% for c in assign_group %}
        <div class="col-md-{{colmd}} well"  style="border:1px solid #CCC">
            <div id="container{{c}}" style="height: 450px"></div>
        </div>
        {%endfor %}
    </div>
```

But it is now displaying all the groups data in my html. How can i prevent this and group the data based on the group? Any idea guys?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: @Leistungsabfall cool, never seen this part in the docs for so long.. django with hidden golden features... ;)

Comment: @Leistungsabfall: Fruitful. But am quiet confused about how I can implement that in this scneario.